# Fresh Ubuntu and GRUB shows multiple Ubuntus and Windows 10s

Tags: grub2

Fresh Ubuntu and GRUB shows multiple Ubuntus and Windows 10s.

sda1 got a fresh install, and sda2 is entirely free space.

Should I do something about this? What?

[image]

Comment: Do you REALLY want to know the cause? Or do you just want to know how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Wipe all drives once again, and reinstall.

There's still a Windows 10 entry for sda referring to the ~500MB boot partition, but this seems to be a feature of Ubuntu, os-prober and/or GRUB.